# Graphical system broken after AMD->Nvidia upgrade. How to re-install all graphical components?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, upgrade, ati, graphics

I've upgraded my AMD HD4770 with an Nvidia GTX 960. When I boot into Ubuntu, the screen is mostly black with some red artifacts at the top. I can switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to a terminal. I've tried removing the AMD drivers and re-installing Nvidia drivers, but it doesn't boot up the graphical interface.

To verify that the new graphics cards are working , I've booted into Windows and there it works perfectly fine and runs at full performance.

So what can I do to basically re-install the graphical components nicely so it works with my new Nvidia card. If this is 'too hard' I can understand. Completely wiping the system and re-installing Ubuntu entirely is an option, but I do not prefer that route as I'm very happy with the way my system is set up now.

System: 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64 Bit on `Linux-generic -kernel-3.16` .
Note: I am Very comfortable with command line, editing config files etc.

Comment: Are you using the OEM drivers? as in: us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/346.47/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run

Comment: I tried using the nvidia-current drivers from the repository.

Comment: try the OEM version. You will need to run from an actual shell, and use root, and kill all X type processes before running it.

Comment: I will give that a go.

Comment: It did work. But I had to re-install xorg as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is more for completeness at this point;
use the OEM driver available from:
http://www.geforce.com/drivers

You will need to run the driver install script from a root terminal, and kill all the X related processes before running it. You may also need to chmod +x the script.

It is also note worthy, that the OEM driver recompiles the kernel. If you upgrade your kernel, (as in normal kernel updates) you will need to rerun the OEM driver script.

Comment: Good one! ;-) (Upvoted!)