# NVIDIA GTX 750Ti Doesn't Work

Tags: nvidia, graphics

My graphics card (NVIDIA GTX 750Ti) will display the BIOS, GRUB, then a black screen on launch. I know that this is a graphics card problem because the only way to see Ubuntu is by switching the monitor to the motherboard rather than the graphics card. This means I can access Ubuntu, but I can't use my graphics card, and thus can't play graphically intensive games.

Comment: try installing OEM drivers. Follow the directions here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/596287/graphical-system-broken-after-amd-nvidia-upgrade-how-to-re-install-all-graphic/597187#597187

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

Answered here : https://askubuntu.com/a/111298/389736

Then when you booted in, install proper driver for your GPU.

Comment: The problem is, I can access Ubuntu just by using another HDMI monitor, but the real issue is installing a NVIDIA driver and have it let me use the graphics card, and not destroy Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Which Ubuntu version? Ubuntu packages are generally recommended instead of direct from nvidia.com, so everything is coordinated and updates automatically. If you need a newer version than in standard repos, there are ppa packages available for that.

I have not tried 14.04.2 or 14.10 yet, but 64-bit 14.04.1 live/install iso, graphics seemed to work fine for my GTX 750 Ti using **nomodeset** boot parameter. However, once installed it would not get to gui login screen because the Maxwell chip apparently was not supported by nouveau yet. And I could not even log into text console (Ctrl+Alt_F1) which would flash motd and immediately return to login prompt.

When I installed nvidia-current from recovery boot by (enabling networking, going to root console, installing it and rebooting, that got me as far as login gui, but could not start X because that nvidia 304 version did not support my card according to logs (even though an updated 304 version in 12.04 worked for it).

So I would suggest booting to recovery mode (which I believe automatically uses nomodeset), enable networking from menu (wait for it to return to menu if any errors), then go to root console from menu. Normally you would use "sudo " prefix for these commands, but sudo is not needed from root console. If you previously installed any nvidia package (like nvidia-current) do `apt-get purge nvidia*` then do:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nvidia-331-updates
reboot
```

That version worked for my GTX 750 Ti, although, I later purged that and am running nvidia-346 from xorg-edgers ppa which is no faster by default, but allows me to play with video overclocking.

If you did not use **nomodeset** during install, you may need to edit (e) the linux line while in grub during boot adding nomodeset to the end of it. Then edit /etc/default/grub to add nomodeset to this line like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`

NOTE: Do not use nomodeset for hybrid Intel/Nvidia graphics on a laptop. I heard that could cause issues with hybrid graphics and everything worked fine without nomodeset when installing 14.04.1 to my laptop with Intel HD 4600/Nvidia GTX 765m graphics using nvidia-331-updates package.

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately, after installing the driver the screen is still a black screen with a blinking cursor